# GAE Python and Jinja2 custom login and user information model

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

i want to use GAE Python and Jinja2 for a web application with custom login form, i need create my own login page and authenticate with google accounts but dont use the google login page, aditional to this i want to save custom information about the user (role, phone, cellphone, address...) and asociate with the google account, some one know a good tutorial for this or any one can bring me some example like this, i'm newbie with this enviroment, thanks you so much in advance.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible (by design) to use google's auth and use a custom login page.  This would be a recipe for a lot of phishing and other assorted attacks.

Comment: Consider using oauth2 and Flask

Comment: Something like this: https://gae-init.appspot.com/signin/? it's using oauth2 and Flask

Comment: Correct @lipis something like that i think works for me, could you please tell me what you did with this?

Comment: I built it.. :) and you can simply fork it and use it...

Comment: A good place to start is the documentation.

Comment: @Lipis i try to work with your code but i have some issues, when i add the code in to the GAELauncher and try to run, i have the message in the log that dont have an app.yaml file in my root directory, when move the main/app.yaml file to the root directory i can deploy the code but in appspot.com I was recibe the message "500 Error: Server Error, The server ...", you have some idea how can configure your code for the main/app.yaml will be correct? or what can i do for the app.yaml file

Comment: @ltahuite in short is not exactly how this community works and I won't be able to resolve all your issues from comments.. Try to complete the [tutorial](http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com/tutorial/), which tells you the steps that you have to follow. It's not running out of the box with the launcher and you will have to execute successfully the `run.py` script first.